# How to absolute position DIV of unknown width

Tags: html, css

- My layout consists of 3 `DIV`s
- The first `DIV`is a wrapper.
- The second `DIV` is centered and uses `max-width:980px;` Otherwise it defaults to 100% width.
- The third `DIV` is 200px wide and uses `absolute position`.  `right:-200px`and `top:0px` position it next to the first `DIV`

This layout works perfect but only because the last `DIV`has a width of 200px.  If that `DIV` had a variable width I couldn't use `right:-200px` and it wouldn't place correctly.

So my question is what would I do if the `DIV` with `absolute position` had a variable width?  How would I place it next to the main `DIV`?

Here is my code.

```
<div class="outer_container">
<div class="internal_alignment">
    <div class="main_container"></div>
    <div class="column_outside"></div>
</div>              
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.internal_alignment {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.main_container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.column_outside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -200px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

FYI: the outer_container `DIV` allows column_outside to sit outside the screen if the browser is smaller than 980px wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Make it a child of the main and give it `left: 100%;`</strike>

```css
.outer_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.internal_alignment {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.main_container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.column_outside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_container">
  <div class="internal_alignment">
    <div class="main_container">

       <div class="column_outside"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

After a second thought, simply use `left: 100%` instead of `right: -200px;`

```css
.outer_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.internal_alignment {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.main_container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.column_outside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_container">
  <div class="internal_alignment">
    <div class="main_container"></div>
    <div class="column_outside"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All 3 solutions worked perfect (thanks!) but your's was the shortest.  I put some words in column_outside and the `DIV` became super narrow.  I added `min-width:100px;` and the layout still held together perfect.  I have so much to learn.  8-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform: translateX(100%);` what it does is to move the element to the right of the amount of the width of the element itself.

```
right: 0;
transform: translateX(100%);
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

```
.column_outside {
   right: 0px;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
   -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
   transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/n4nq6Lxt/

No need to change your HTML structure.

Comment: I'm going to keep `transform` in mind.  I know it will come in handy.